# How to draw sine wave graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, axis

How to draw sine wave graph which starts at (-5, 0.5) and ends at (5, 1.5)?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x(t)$, ylabel=$t$, grid=major,xmin=-5
xmax=5, ymin=-2, ymax=2, domain=-5:5]
\addplot[blue, line width=1pt, samples=20]
expression{sin(180*x) ??? };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems thatyou like to draw superposition `$0.5 + \sin(x)$`. This function in `pgfplots` is `{0.5+sin(180*x)}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x(t)$, ylabel=$t$, 
    grid=major,
    xmin=-5, xmax=5, 
    ymin=-2, ymax=2, 
    domain=-5:4.5,
    samples=201]
\addplot[blue, line width=1pt] {0.5+sin(180*x)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks soo much !!

Comment: @Amy, if you have new question, please ask it as such. In comment will not see it many people, who will know to help you. In question please be more specific, what is your problem.

Comment: @Amy, if answer help you, you can up-vote it :-)  or even accept it :-) :-)

Comment: It helped, and I up-voted it..sorry for being late..Thank you :)